# SQL Server: Copy database error: the share name has to be specified for

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently trying to copy a database to another server using sql server 2008 r2. I have done this many times but I get this error:

### TITLE: Copy Database Wizard

The share name has to be specified for database xxxx

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it means that the public name of your DB has to be unique. You need that name to connect to the DB remotely. You can't run the same DB twice on a machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest entering a location where data is stored on the source server. It just asks where to store migrated files. For example:
*D:\MSSQL\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA*

as Imran Ali Khan suggested this is documentation on how to do it

> Copy Database Wizard (Location of Source Database Files)
>
> If the source and destination server instances are on different computers, you  must specify a file system share that contains the database files on the source server.
>      Options
>      Database
>      Displays the name of each database being moved.
>      Folder location
>      Specify the location of the source database files on the file system.
>      For example: 
>      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
>
> File share on source server
>      Specify the location of the source database files as a path of a file share.
>      For example: 
>      "\server_name\C$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data"

Source of information 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187680(v=sql.105).aspx